# animation delay relative to nth position in list

Tags: css, vue.js, sass

I have a horizontal list and i wand a kind of wave of them coming up. So 5th child will come up in 5 seconds, 10th child in 10 seconds etc.

I dont want to mess up the elements below it by putting a margin-top so im doing it on the span inside the list like so...

```
<ul>
    <li v-for="( achievement, index ) in achievements" :key="index">
        <span></span>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Scss...

```
@keyframes fadeInUp {
  0% {
    opacity:0;
    margin-top: 125px;
  }
  100% {
    opacity:1;
    margin-top: 0;
  }
}

ul {

    li {

        @for $i from 1 through 3 {
          &:nth-child(#{$i}n) {
            span {
              animation-delay: #{$i * 4.5}s;
            }
          }
        } 

        span {
            position: absolute;
            animation: fadeInUp;
        }
    }
}
```

Ive stripped out the content so its easy to read. The delay gets applied if i apply it to the list, but It wont go to the span.

Comment: I don't have the time atm to analyse this code, but wouldn't applying `:style="{ animationDelay:  4.5 * index + 's' }"` on each line easier?

Comment: I cant believe i didn't think of that, that should work, ill give it a try